# Yii2 Internationalization component automatic translation?

Tags: php, yii2

I just installed Internationalization component on my application for Arabic language.

I didn't translate any of the validation messages but they are appearing translated when I use the app? Where is it getting these translations from? Can I change these translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translations are under

```
vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages
```

To learn how Yii2 support internationalization may worthwhile this link:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html